# QWebException: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1) [Odoo/Openerp]

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I created a custom module that computes total invoice from each customer or supplier payment voucher. It returns an error whenever I call the report.

```
QWebException: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)
```

**module: module_pdc**

**models/outstanding_pdc.py**

```
from openerp import fields, api, models, exceptions
from datetime import datetime
from openerp.tools.translate import _
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class AccountOutstandingPostDatedCheck(models.Model):
    _name = 'account.post.dated.check.outstanding'
    _description = 'Outstanding Receivable'

    name = fields.Char(string='Reference No.')    
    is_customer = fields.Boolean('Customers')
    is_supplier = fields.Boolean('Suppliers')    
    outstanding_pdc_line_ids = fields.One2many('account.post.dated.check.outstanding.line', 'outstanding_line_id', 'Outstanding Receivable Line')

    @api.model    
    def create(self, values):
        sequence_obj = self.env['ir.sequence']      
        values.update({'name' : sequence_obj.next_by_code('pdc.outstanding.ref')})    
        return super(AccountOutstandingPostDatedCheck,self).create(values)  

    @api.multi    
    def check_outstanding_pdc(self):
        customer = self.is_customer
        supplier = self.is_supplier    


        # Create object classes to access records.   
        account_voucher = self.env['account.voucher']    
        outstanding_pdc_line_ids = self.env['account.post.dated.check.outstanding.line']


        # Clear the list before execution of the main process:    
        if self.outstanding_pdc_line_ids.ids != []:    
            self.outstanding_pdc_line_ids.unlink()

        #Search the voucher within the selected period    
        date_today = datetime.now().date()    
        date_today = date_today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        pdc_vouchers = []
        if customer and supplier:    
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('Select only one partner.'))    
        if not customer and not supplier:    
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('Select one partner.'))
        elif customer:    
            pdc_vouchers = account_voucher.search([('post_dated', '=', True), ('state','=','posted'), ('partner_id.customer', '=', True), ('payment_details.type', '=', 'check'), ('payment_details.date_due', '>', date_today)])   
        elif supplier:   
            pdc_vouchers = account_voucher.search([('post_dated', '=', True), ('state','=','posted'), ('partner_id.supplier', '=', True), ('payment_details.type', '=', 'check'), ('payment_details.date_due', '>', date_today)])    

        # Loop through each Voucher and collect its Partner Ids.    
        partners = []    
        for voucher in pdc_vouchers:    
            if voucher.partner_id not in partners: partners.append(voucher.partner_id)
        receivable = 0.00
        envelope = 0.00    
        pdc = 0.00

        for partner in partners:   
            for pdc_voucher in pdc_vouchers:    
                if pdc_voucher.partner_id == partner:    
                    for voucher_line in pdc_voucher.line_ids:    
                        receivable += voucher_line.amount_original    
                        if not voucher_line.move_line_id.invoice.reconciled:    
                            envelope += voucher_line.move_line_id.invoice.residual                       

                    pdc = receivable - envelope 
                vals = {  
                    'outstanding_line_id' : self.ids[0],   
                    'partner_id': partner.id,    
                    'receivable': receivable,   
                    'pdc':  pdc,    
                    'envelope': envelope    
                }   

            receivable = 0.00    
            envelope = 0.00    
            pdc = 0.00   
            outstanding_pdc_line_ids.create(vals)



class AccountPostDatedCheckOutstandingLine(models.Model): 
    _name = "account.post.dated.check.outstanding.line"  
    _description = "Outstanding Receivable Line"  


    outstanding_line_id = fields.Many2one('account.post.dated.check.outstanding', 'Outstanding Receivable Line')    
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Partner')    
    receivable = fields.Float('Receivable')    
    pdc= fields.Float('PDC')    
    envelope = fields.Float('Envelope')
```

**views/report_outstanding_pdc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>    
<data>    
<template id="report_outstanding_pdc_document">   
    <t t-call="report.html_container">    
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">    
            <t t-call="module_pdc.outstanding_pdc_layout">    
                <div class="page">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">    
                        <thead>    
                            <tr>   
                                <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>   
                                <th class="col-xs-3">Receivable</th>   
                                <th class="col-xs-3">PDC</th>  
                                <th class="col-xs-3">Envelope</th>  
                            </tr>   
                        </thead>   

                        <tr t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="or">  
                            <td class="col-xs-3">  
                                <span t-field="or.partner_id"/>    
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-xs-3">    
                                <span t-field="or.receivable"/>    
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-xs-3">   
                                <span t-field="or.pdc"/>   
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-xs-3">   
                                <span t-field="or.envelope"/>  
                            </td>   
                        </tr>

                        <t t-set="rec" t-value="0.00"/>   
                            <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="r">  
                            <t t-set="rec" t-value="rec+r.receivable"/>     
                            </t> 

                        <t t-set="pd" t-value="0.00"/>     
                            <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="p">   
                                <t t-set="pd" t-value="pd+p.pdc"/>    
                            </t>

                        <t t-set="env" t-value="0.00"/>     
                            <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="e">  
                                <t t-set="env" t-value="env+e.envelope"/>    
                            </t> 

                        <tr>    
                              <th class="col-xs-3"><strong>Total:</strong></th>    
                              <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="rec"/>    
                              <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="pd"/>    
                              <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="env"/>     
                        </tr>    
                    </table>        
                </div>    
            </t>
        </t>    
    </t>    
</template>    
</data>    
</openerp>
```

Comment: Please when posting code like this make sure that it does not have those annoying empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the problem in my template.

```
<tr t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="or">
```

Instead of **or**, I used different name for my one2many field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's something wrong with your qweb template code.

Try this code

```
<openerp>
<data>

    <template id="report_outstanding_pdc_document">

        <div class="page">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-3">Receivable</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-3">PDC</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-3">Envelope</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="or">
                    <td class="col-xs-3">
                        <span t-field="or.partner_id" />
                    </td>

                    <td class="col-xs-3">
                        <span t-field="or.receivable" />
                    </td>

                    <td class="col-xs-3">
                        <span t-field="or.pdc" />
                    </td>

                    <td class="col-xs-3">
                        <span t-field="or.envelope" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <t t-set="rec" t-value="0.00" />
                <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="r">
                    <t t-set="rec" t-value="rec+r.receivable" />
                </t>

                <t t-set="pd" t-value="0.00" />
                <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="p">
                    <t t-set="pd" t-value="pd+p.pdc" />
                </t>

                <t t-set="env" t-value="0.00" />
                <t t-foreach="o.outstanding_pdc_line_ids" t-as="e">
                    <t t-set="env" t-value="env+e.envelope" />
                </t>

                <tr>
                    <th class="col-xs-3">
                        <strong>Total:</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="rec" />
                    <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="pd" />
                    <th class="col-xs-3" t-esc="env" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </template>


    <template id="report_outstanding_pdc">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="module_pdc.report_outstanding_pdc_document" />
        </t>
    </template>

</data></openerp>
```

Also alter your python script as per this qweb template. 
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I found what was the problem in my template :)